# Start bounty on Stackoverflow.com question and got Page Not Found

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, bounties

I tried to start bounty here:

[Get base64 of audio data from Cordova Capture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29192327/get-base64-of-audio-data-from-cordova-capture)

But I got this strange error after I submitted:

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: *Fatal Error*: inbox overflow :D